# Visual Studio for Mac Web API template project does not include AccountController

Tags: templates, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-mac

I am using VS for Mac and the default project created by the new Web API project is not as complete as the 2015...

Is there somewhere to get either templates for VS for Mac or simply download a default solution which is equivalent to the VS 2015 new project for a Web API 2.2 project?

FYI: I am following this and it references the AccountsController, which is not included in the default Web API project:

http://johnatten.com/2014/09/21/asp-net-identity-2-0-introduction-to-working-with-identity-2-0-and-web-api-2-2/